# django: set custom user manager on existing user model

Tags: django

I want to achieve case-insensitive login in django. I know about this:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        return self.get(username__iexact=username)
```

But what do I actually do with it? I don't want to change or subclass the existing user model if I can help it. Do I have to?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to change your is user model manager.
To override model manager all you have to do is something like this.

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = MyUserManager()
```

Now you can make a filter like the following.

```
MyUser.objects.get_by_natural_key('the-user-name-requested')
```